# Tomcat: ClassCastException entre java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 y java.util.Map

Tags: java, tomcat

como soluciono este error que hace que Apache Tomcat se detenga?

este es el error:

> 28-Oct-2022 21:30:05.162 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches for web application [docs]

> ```
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Segun [esta liga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457793/classcastexception-when-stopping-tomcat-10-inside-eclipse) del sitio en gringo, el problema puede deberse a la versionde  tomcat que tienes instalado.

Ellos sugieren instalar la version `8.5.82`

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora lo intentaré:)